# Separate specific value in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a large dataset. I am trying to read it with Pandas Dataframe. I want to separate some values from one of the columns. Assuming the name of column is "A", there are values ranging from 90 to 300. I want to separate any values between 270 to 280. I did try below code but it is wrong!

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.read_csv('....csv')
df2 = df[ 270 < df['A'] < 280]
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':range(90,300)})

df2 = df[df['A'].between(270,280, inclusive=False)]
print (df2)
      A
181  271
182  272
183  273
184  274
185  275
186  276
187  277
188  278
189  279
```

Or:

```
df2 = df[(df['A'] > 270) & (df['A'] < 280)]
print (df2)
      A
181  271
182  272
183  273
184  274
185  275
186  276
187  277
188  278
189  279
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `numpy` to speed things up and reconstruct a new dataframe.
*Assuming we use jezrael's sample data*

```
a = df.A.values
m = (a > 270) & (a < 280) 
pd.DataFrame(a[m], df.index[m], df.columns)

       A
181  271
182  272
183  273
184  274
185  275
186  276
187  277
188  278
189  279
```

Comment: Which part of that is numpy?

Comment: @pshep123 - if call `a = df.A.values` get numpy array and then `a[m]` and `df.index[m]` is for filtering of arrays (array of values of column A and array of index values) - here same boolean indexing works in numpy also as in pandas.

Comment: Ahhh, so by working with the one-dimensional array (`values`), you are, by default, using numpy. Got it, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [query()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) method:

```
df2 = df.query("270 < A < 280")
```

Demo:

```
In [40]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A':range(90,300)})

In [41]: df.query("270 < A < 280")
Out[41]:
       A
181  271
182  272
183  273
184  274
185  275
186  276
187  277
188  278
189  279
```

Comment: I am getting error with this! UndefinedVariableError: name 'A' is not defined

Comment: @user8034918, are you sure you have a column named `A`?